# How to not kill more than 2 entities using /kill without using scoreboard in minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am trying to kill all entities that are not a player and a sheep called test catch but I can't use

```
/kill @e[type=!Player,!sheep]
```

so how could it be done WITHOUT scoreboard because I don't want to keep doing scoreboard for everything that deserves and that doesn't. and please don't judge me because I don't want to use scoreboard.

Comment: What's the reason you don't want to use `/scoreboard`? Scoreboard tags would be the best way to do this that I could think of.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: I swear I did, but the only things I found was using scoreboard, I don't see why everybody just dislikes the question instantly just because I don't want to use scoreboard, I don't see in the rules of the site that I must use a scoreboard

Comment: No, the rules state you have to show effort. Pigeonholing yourself with such a specific requirement, without a good reason, is going to draw downvotes; its an inane requirement, without any usefulness. You're just making life harder on yourself.

Comment: I didn't know about the tags, and someone just informed me about it, so why am I mistaken

Comment: Because if you had done some research on your own, you would have realized tags were a thing, and we'd have a much  more specific question. And we'd see that you tried to solve it on your own, which makes it even better.

Comment: as I said, I did research but found nothing except using scoreboard, you are abusing your privileges

Comment: What research? You haven't shown us anything. We don't know that you did; your question doesn't show any. Its not abuse; its the entire *point* of down voting.

Comment: While this question wasn't a duplicate when it was asked, Minecraft 1.13 changed things so the optimum way of selecting all but two types of entities no longer used a scoreboard (hence the accepted answer to the possible duplicate), meaning this question is not a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way without using `/scoreboard` is to manually target each entity type that you want to kill, being a very long list of commands (~80):

```
/kill @e[type=armor_stand]
/kill @e[type=skeleton]
/kill @e[type=item]
/kill @e[type=ghast]
...
```

Which also means that any new entities being added to the game won't be included and you'd have to manually add new `/kill` commands.

---

You should *really* be using `/scoreboard` for this. If your worry is bloating the scoreboard with objectives, then you use the "tag" feature instead. I should emphasis that the "tag" feature has essentially **nothing** to do with the scoreboard, and its usage with `/scoreboard` is misleading in that sense.

Entities have a list of generic string data that can be directly associated with them, and it just happens that `/scoreboard` can interact with that list. There is no relation to the scoreboard otherwise.

For example, the following greatly simplifies what the above does, and makes it future-proof:

1. Assign a custom label to entities that you **don't** want to kill, provided they don't already have that label. Once again, this does **not** interact with the scoreboard and makes no use of objectives.

   ```
   /scoreboard players tag @e[type=player,tag=!nokill] add nokill
   /scoreboard players tag @e[type=sheep,tag=!nokill] add nokill
   ```
2. Kill entities that do not have that label.

   ```
   /kill @e[tag=!nokill]
   ```

The result is only 3 commands versus 80+, no objectives or scoreboard interaction, and will not break in the future when new entities are added to the game.

Comment: thank you that really helped, I didn't know about tags

Comment: Another way to do it in one command is 
/execute @e[type=!Player] ~ ~ ~ /kill @e[type=!sheep,r=0]
if you keep stacking the /execute command you can increase it to any number of mobs you don't want to kill. the r=0 makes it so that a player won't die if he is in a 1 block hole with 50 cows.

Comment: @LethaIity Unfortunately `r=0` is not infallible. If there's any conflict at all with a player overlapping any entity, such as from `/tp`, that will kill the player. While it's a simple solution (and should probably be used instead of 80+ commands!), it does come with that unavoidable issue. The "tags" feature does not have any targeting flaws and so should be used over `/execute`, lest the player die unexpectedly.

Comment: Ah didn't realize that. from my personal experiences and from what other people said I assumed otherwise.